# Cannot connect to my TFS project

Tags: tfs

This seems a simple question but I am stuck.

I have just had to rebuild my server (hosted on Fasthosts) and also rebuild my dev pc.

I have installed TFS 2015 back onto my windows 2012 server.

i have reinstalled Vs2017 on my dev PC.

I have created a Team Project in TFS.

I have used vs2017 on my dev pc. I have gone to manage connections.  I have typed in:

http://My_hosted_server_IP:8080/tfs

It comes as cannot connect.

I can connect via my VS2017 installed on my server though.

I cannot remember what else i have to do to get access to my TFS collection.

Also I have deleted the caches locally and on the server

Someone please advise?

Thanks

ADDITIONAL:

The very 1st thing I do in these situations is turn off the firewalls but this did nothing. So, i thought it was a binding issue. I tried to 1st enable better tracing in the log file for TFS but that gave me nothing. There was also nothing in the event viewer.

I could view the tfs web services directly via a browser on the server so was really mystified.

I looked in the allowed TCP ports and I could see 8080 was opened both ways.

In the end I solved this by per chance by discovering that a freebie anti-virus software was installed somehow and by removing this i could eventually ping the server.

However, at this stage I still could not connect via my ide to tfs.

The clincher was again to disable firewalls and it did work.

So, there was something in the frewall options that was stopping this conection.

I was that Team Foundation Services needed the Public option checked too.

Al pretty obvious in the end. But it was a combination of things..

[image]

Comment: Please add detail error message when you connect your VS2017 to TFS. This is helpful to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Hi, you are quite right. However, i had solved this but forgot to delete.  I shall comment on the provided answer as it may be useful to other people

Comment: Hi @Andrew, glad to here the issue fixed. Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:) Yes you 're right. You could share your solution here and mark it as an answer  which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT well I accepted yours and just appended to it in my answer. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general situation (connectivity issue). To  narrow down this problem, try the following actions:

- Check whether there is something useful in **Event View** on your TFS
  server
- Give a try with directly using IP address instead of server name when
  you are adding Team Foundation Sever in VS2017. Something like:
  `http://192.168.0.1:8080/tfs`
- Login in tfs **web portal** in web browser on your develop machine to see
  if it's only a VS related issue
- Run VS2017 in Administrator Mode.
- Turn off your firewall temporarily, disable anti-virus software.

For more ways to trouble shooting please take a look at this blog: [TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/cant-connect-team-foundation-server/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. just realised it was you again :).  The approach I took was similar to you. I have edited my question. thanks again